# Put an image in a string

Tags: javascript, image

Hy, i want to put a serverside image into a string to work with it.
How it is possible?

I searching for something like that

```
var image = loadFile("../images/cover.jpg");
```

I want to use the image for the share API

```
if(navigator.canShare) {
            navigator.share({
                text: "text",
                files: file,
                title: "title",
                url: "https://www...."
            });
    }
```

Comment: Could you share some more detail? For instance, are you using Express.js?

Comment: What do you mean by put an image in a string ?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "image into a string", how you're planning to "work with it", whether this is client or server-side/your current resources, and what code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can using base64 string and then use it on your web page.
Like this:

```
const b64Img = fetch(...someImageLinkUrl)
document.body.innerHTML = `<img src='data:image/png;base64, ${b64Img}'/>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are searching for is an image to base64 string representation conversion.

Check this npm package [image-to-base64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-base64)

it should help you achieve the desired functionality.